# In web.xml, how to describe a file to avoid FileNotFoundException?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've wandered through a variety of posts.  Each one has different answers.  None are working for me.

I want to get a lot of config files out of my WEB-INF directory.  I will put all of them into a "spring" subdirectory.

web.xml has this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>spring/exchangeboard-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The file WEB-INF/spring/exchangeboard-context.xml has this:

```
<import resource="spring-context.xml" />
<import resource="spring-security.xml" />
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
```

There are no external references in the first two includes.  The third file, located as WEB-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml, has this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="db.properties" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:configLocation="hibernate.cfg.xml"
    p:packagesToScan="mystuff.exchangeboard"/>
```

In short, web.xml points at a file in the "spring" subdirectory and all of those files refer to each other within that subdirectory.

When I start the server I get this result:

```
[snip] nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/spring/exchangeboard-context.xml]
```

I've tried a variety of solutions --

```
classpath:/WEB-INF/spring/exchangeboard-context.xml

classpath:spring/exchangeboard-context.xml

/WEB-INF/spring/exchangeboard-context.xml

/spring/exchangeboard-context.xml
```

with no good results.

What is the proper phrasing here?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Comment: how are you packaging the war? can you verify whether the context file is actually present in the deployed war?

Comment: Eclipse (STS) auto-builds the WAR.  In a recent (2PM today) version of the WAR it does include the WEB-INF, META-INF, etc., directories in the WAR file.  Since then I've edited the project to "something that works", using /WEB-INF/spring/filename hard-coded where needed.  I'd like to get rid of the /WEB-INF business.